# Using modularity() function in R to find modularity of each subgroup in network

Tags: r, igraph, modularity, network-analysis

I have a network calle Passes, encompassing 6 players (A-F) where ABC are in one team X, and DEF are in team Y. The numbers are the count of passes from one player (id) to the other (tid). I want to find the modularity of each team.

```
Passes <- data.frame(
  id = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F"), 
  tid = c("B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "F", "A", "B", "D", "E"), 
  Number = c(14,5,1,10,23,4,1,3,5,10)
)
```

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph.data.frame(Passes, directed = TRUE)
set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value= E(g)$Number)
Passes$Team <- ""
names(Passes)[3] <- "Number"
# assign team names based on "id" column
X <- unique(Passes$id)[1:3]
Y <- unique(Passes$id)[4:6]

Passes$Team[Passes$id %in% X] <- "X"
Passes$Team[Passes$id %in% Y] <- "Y"

X_mod <- modularity(g, membership = (V(g)$Team == "X"))
Y_mod <- modularity(g, membership = V(g)$Team == "Y")

#this is my second attempt after getting error message
X_mod <- modularity(g, membership = as.integer(Passes$id %in% X))
Y_mod <- modularity(g, membership = as.integer(Passes$id %in% Y))
```

But I still get error message:
Error in modularity.igraph(g, membership = V(g)$Team == "X") :
Membership is not a numerical vector
or
Error in modularity.igraph(g, membership = as.integer(V(g)$Team == "X")) :
At core/community/modularity.c:132 : Membership vector size differs from number of vertices. Invalid value

What am I doing wrong, or am I just not understanding the membership= parameter very well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your comment disappeared form under the accepted answer just before I posted mine, so I'm not sure you got the notification. Please check what I wrote there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting the values of `Passes$Team` but you are not setting any Team attributes on your `g` graph object. When you call `graph.data.frame`, it takes the data in the data.frame and creates a new graph object. It is no longer lined to that data.frame so any changes you make to the data.frame afterward will not be reflected in the graph object. You probably want something more like

```
V(g)[V(g)$name %in% X]$Team <- "X"
V(g)[V(g)$name %in% Y]$Team <- "Y"
```

and then you can calculate modularity with

```
modularity(g, membership = (V(g)$Team == "X")+1)
modularity(g, membership = (V(g)$Team == "Y")+1)
```

because it seems the membership needs to be a non-zero positive integer value, so adding 1 to a boolean will take the values from TRUE/FALSE to 2/1

Comment: @EmmyW, you say "I want to find the modularity of each team." It seems you are misunderstanding what modularity is. It does not characterize a subset of vertices. It makes no sense to ask what is the modularity of "X", what is the modularity of "Y". Modularity is used to characterize _a partitioning of a graph_. Once you broke the graph into parts (e.g. teams), you can get a single value for that partitioning. Mr Flick, both lines given in this answer compute the same thing.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for explaining, I realised that too therefore i deleted my last comment.